# No rep refund after bounty expired?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounty

I understand that the bounty [on my SF question](https://serverfault.com/questions/858922/lvm-metadata-missing-trying-to-recreate-raid-1-with-lvm) may not be refunded and automatically awarded if there is at least one answer, but I still lose the 50 rep I posted as bounty if there are no answers? That doesn't seem right to me. If nobody posted a single answer, is that to imply that my question wasn't good enough to be answered?

Comment: You're paying for the advertising, not the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is correct - [bounties are non-refundable](https://serverfault.com/help/bounty).

There are many reasons why you might have not get an answer:

- no one is interested in it or at least no one knowing a solution
- it's also strictly [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) here (and has now been migrated).
- Many of our high-rep users are most likely not interested in bounties at all, let alone something as silly as 50 points.

NB: My solution to that problem would have been to restore from backup.

Comment: For someone without a lot of rep, I wouldn't call any bounty "silly", but that's just me. And restoring from backup already didn't work.